# Adding digits in an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var myArr = [ '111' , '222' , '333' ] ;
```

I would like this to become `[3, 6, 9]` essentially summing up the digits. Would a nested for-loop or map be the best route to achieve this?

Comment: OP, while you have a number of answers here, for future reference it's important that you attempt the solution yourself and if you run into problems post _that_ as your question so we can see what you've tried, rather than using SO as a coding service.

Comment: Also funny: `result=myArr.map(x=>eval([...x].join('+')))`

Answer (score 2):

You can map and evaluate the sum reducing the regex matches for each digit:

```js
var myArr = [ '111' , '222' , '333' ];

var result = myArr.map(function(text){
    return text.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(x, y){
        return +y + x;
    }, 0);
});

O.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd maybe do something like this:

```
myArr.map(function(a){
    var temp = 0;
    a.split('').forEach(function(b){
        temp += parseInt(b,10);
    });
    return temp;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parseString = function(n) { 
    return n.split('')
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
                  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
           })
    };

myArr.map(function(str) {return   parseString(str)})
```

Comment: Do make sure you add an explanation to help people better understand your answer, rather than just leaving a chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fiddle gives you the result you are after:

```
var myArr = [ "111" , "222" , "333" ] ;
var newArr = myArr.map(function(string){
    var chars = string.split("")
  var value = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ){
    value = value + parseInt(chars[i])
  }
  return value;
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bw7s6yey/

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 approach in two lines.

```
const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((p, c) => +p + +c);
let out = myArr.map(el => sum([...el]));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t7xpeedj/2/)

Comment: ES6 allows you to use `[...el]` instead of `el.split('')`